# complex event handling in dropdown.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

hey guys i am new to Jquery and i am learning how to deal with event , i have made a few events myself eg.

```
(document).on('click' , function(){
   alert ('ok')
});
```

But i was just going through the bootstrap dropdown.js code and came across the following line of code :

```
$parent.trigger(e = $.Event('hide.bs.dropdown', relatedTarget));
```

this seems to use the trigger method of Jquery to trigger an event artificially , like i have seen in alot of examples ,  the syntex

```
$parent.trigger(e);
```

makes sense to me ,but the below syntax does't :

```
$parent.trigger(e = $.Event('hide.bs.dropdown', relatedTarget))
```

i know that () in javascript is used to allow a certain execution to be performed before further execution can be performed , eg  :  `(1 * 10) + 2;` here the result of 1 * 10 is calculated first and then added to 2 , but i still don't get the trigger syntax used , this line of syntax can also be found on [git](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/dropdown.js#L104) .

Comment: They just manually construct event object. Take a look at the doc for details https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

Comment: @dfsq thanks .. will read tat .

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about the syntax, () in this context is to pass parameters to the function. If you break it down this works the same way:

```
    var customEvent = $.Event('hide.bs.dropdown', relatedTarget);
    $parent.trigger(customEvent);
```

Like dfsq mentioned, they are constructing a custom event object.